# How to horizontally align an inner layout

Tags: java, android, layout, alignment

Within a dialog I am trying to create a `LinearLayout` containing *first* a `TextView` and *second* a `GridLayout` programmatically (not by defining an xml-layout). How can I make the inner `GridLayout` center horizontally within the outer `LinearLayout`.

**Desired_layout:**

[image: desired_layout]

For the inner `TextView` it is quite simple (via `setGravity`). But I cannot figure out how to do it for the `GridLayout`. I messed around with setting `LayoutParams` to the outer layout and to the inner layout, but could not find a way.

*btw*: I understand that the difference between the xml-attributes `android:layout_gravity` and `android:gravity` is basically defining layout for the containing child views and for the view itself, but why is there no corresponding java method like `setLayoutGravity()` but only `setGravity()`?

```
LinearLayout outerLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
outerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
TextView txtView = new TextView(getContext());
txtView.setText("Hello world");
txtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
GridLayout innerLayout = _buildMyGridLayout(getContext());
//what to do with the innerLayout?
outerLayout.addView(txtView);
outerLayout.addView(innerLayout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create instance of [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)
2. Set gravity
   via [public field gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#gravity), see also [Gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)
3. Use layout
   params instance for GridLayout (use [addView method with
   LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)))